# Lat long co-ordinates in geojson format for Alaska(smaller), bigger Guam and Puerto Rico?

Tags: maps, leaflet, polygon

Where do I get the geojson format(polygons) of Alaska, Guam and Puerto Rico in different sizes ? The size I have for Alaska is too largeand too small for Guam and Puerto Rico. I'm very new to mapping technologies. It would be great if somebody could point me where I could find the rescaled version (in geo Json) of these states.

Update: the sizes of Guam and Puerto Rico in the current zoom level of my map is so tiny, it's virtually impossible to launch a pop up on clicking those states.
[image]

Comment: Are you hoping to display the polygons in a similar layout to the image you posted? If so, perhaps an inset map is more what you're looking for. You can create small inset map overlays for Alaska, Guam, etc. and specify a different zoom level for each.  That would not require any extra GeoJSON.

Answer (score 0):

The GeoJSON format is supposed to contain the actual true geographical coordinates (latitude and longitude). Alaska is a really big State, whereas Guam is tiny. Furthermore, the Web Mercator projection expands areas at high latitudes (like Alaska), which even increases the size contrast.

Changing the size is normally done through zooming, which indeed raises the problem of showing different areas at different scales on the same figure. The usual workaround is to divide the figure into different maps at different zoom levels, as proposed by nathansnider in the comment.

Still, you can use "fake" coordinates to render your areas at a different size and at another place. Note that your shape will then have completely incorrect coordinates, so any data that you would like to bind to it (like markers, polygons, etc.) would need the exact same conversion.

I am not sure if there is already a service or library that offers this functionality. Otherwise, simply make a small script that iterates over each point of your GeoJSON data, divide each coordinate by a fix scaling value (same for latitude and longitude, or you will distort the shape), and optionally add an offset (could be different for latitude and longitude) to change the position.

The Web Mercator projection will slightly distort the resulting shape, but this should already be a good start.